# Module 'flutter_local_notifications' not found in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

In my app I am using flutter local notifications to push the notifications locally and the version of the package is: `flutter_local_notifications: ^1.4.4+4`. It is working perfectly fine on android. But it is throwing an error on Xcode saying "Module flutter_local_notifications is not found". Not sure what is causing this issue any help is appreciated.

This is my error:

```
fatal error: module 'flutter_local_notifications' not found
    @import flutter_local_notifications;
     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

Comment: Can you please specify the Xcode version and COCOAPODS version?

Comment: CocoaPods: 1.10.0 and Xcode: Version 12.2

Comment: Did you open the ios module in Xcode and try building it?

Comment: Yes that runner.xcworkspace

Comment: Also can you specify Flutter version?

Comment: I ran flutter --version and got the following output:


Flutter 1.22.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 1aafb3a8b9 (4 days ago) • 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800
Engine • revision 2c956a31c0
Tools • Dart 2.10.4

Answer (score 3):

Make your iOS version in pod file same as Xcode deployment info in Xcode refer to below images

**Xcode deployment info**

[image]

**PodFile**

[image]